# NodeJS SFTP get zip file

Tags: node.js, sftp

Trying to get a group of zip files off a server using SFTP. Here's a simplified snippet of code trying to get just a single file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
let sftp = new Client();
sftp.connect({
    host: 'ftp.domain.com',
    port: '22',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
}).then(() => {
    sftp.get("fileName.zip").then((data) => {
        data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('download/fileName.zip'));
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err, 'get error');
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, 'connect error');
});
```

I do get a file downloaded, but while the file on the server is about 1.4 MB, the downloaded one is 2.5 MB and can't be opened with any zip utilities. I suspect it's an encoding issue, but all the answers I've found so far say **not** to set encoding for binary streams.

Answer (score 1):

There's on open issue on the library's github page regarding this issue -> [Corrupt file on the SFTP](https://github.com/jyu213/ssh2-sftp-client/issues/45)

You could try to actually set the encoding to null:

```
sftp.get("fileName.zip", null, null).then(...)
```